# wsl (windows subsystem for linux)のUbuntuがネット非接続時に起動しない

Tags: ubuntu, wsl

これまで問題なくwsl(wsl1)でUbuntu 16.04を使ってきましたが、急に、
起動すると一瞬terminalが開いてすぐ強制終了する事態に陥りました。

その際powershellから起動すると以下のエラーメッセージが表示されました。

> wsl                                                                                                  
>   リモート プロシージャ コールに失敗しました。

この時、ネットワークに接続した状態で起動すると正常起動しますが、ネットワークを
切断した状態で起動すると強制終了します。前者で正常起動した場合、
pingやremoteのlinux serverへのsshなどはこれまで通りできています。

Ubuntu 16.04をアンインストールしUbuntu 18.04をインストールしても同様でした。
他のdistributionはインストールされていません（legacy BoWもアンインストール済み）。
再起動やサインアウト・インを繰り返したり、windowsストアアプリのトラブルシューティングによる修復・リセット、"sfc /scannow"を実施しても解決しませんでした。
サービスのremote desktop services, remote desktop usermode port redirector,
remote desktop configurationを自動起動に設定しても解決しませんでした。
3rd partyのアンチウイルスソフトは使用せずwindows defenderを使っています。
windows defenderでウイルススキャンを実施しましたが異常は検知されませんでした。
OSはwindows10 home insider preview build 18970です。

ネットワークに接続すればこれまで通りwslを使うことができますが、
オフラインで使えない状態なので困っています。
原因として考えられることがありましたらご教示頂けますと幸いです。
どうぞよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 原因究明のため、cmdからWSLを起動してみてはいかがでしょうか。
```strace WSL```。デフォルトでcmdからWSLを起動できるかは設定次第かもしれませんが、こちらの環境では動きました。

Answer (score 1):

解決しました。
オフライン時にDNS情報を取得しようとして失敗することによるらしいです。
以下の情報に従い、ローカル用のDNSを用意することで、
オフラインでもwslを起動できました。

https://qiita.com/birdwatcher/items/3d62c244b48ec94939e3

コメント頂きありがとうございました。

Comment: お疲れ様でした。ユーザー情報を見るに質問時とアカウントが分かれてしまっているようです。アカウントを統合すれば、信用度を稼いだり、自己回答として承認したりすることができます。[こちらのヘルプ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)から統合できますのでご参考までに。

Comment: リンクされているQiitaの記事には「2019/1/23のWindows Updateでこのバグが直った」と書かれていますが、こちらアップデートしても直らない別のバグと推測されるということでしょうか？

Comment: 失礼しました。
「2019/1/23のWindows Updateでこのバグが直った」ではなく、それ以降に記載されている
対応を実施しました。ちなみにwindows updateでは治りませんでした。